# Не получается разделить список, для обработки в потоке PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, asyncio

Мне нужно попилить вводимый пользователем список на 3 части, и записать каждую в отдельный список.
Я решил реализовать это через `NumPy`, так как прочёл, что он быстрее работает с большими списками.
Однако, тут возникла проблема. Если я помещаю код в функцию, то к новым спискам не могут получить доступ никакие методы. Даже внутри этой же функции(просто не видят их). Позже разобравшись, понял что он просто разделяет список на 3 списка, по 1 элементу в каждом. То есть, если изначально был список 
    `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, то он разделит их на `[0 1 2 3 4]` и `[5 6 7 8 9]`.
Так вот. Есть какой-то надёжный способ разделить список и, что очень важно, записать каждую из частей в свой отдельный список? Ну либо мануал по работе со списками вида

```
>>> lst 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

В режиме асинхронности через `asyncio`
Я так понимаю, генератором списков можно, но не совсем представляю как это работает.

Просто по итогу мне нужно, чтобы при обработке каждого элемента списка (он обрабатывается долго), `asyncio` переключал контекст на другую функцию, работающую с другой частью списка, а потом так же на 3-ю, чтобы ускорить обработку всего списка. Такие дела. Заранее спасибо за уделённое внимание.

Ниже прикладываю `main.py`. `Asyncio` в нём не прикручен, потому что сначала мне нужно разбить список. `NumPy` уже выпилен. Нужно бить список `urls`

```
from Souce.ui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import requests
import asyncio
#-------------------Обработка исключений--------------------------

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()

    import sys
    sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

#------------------Thread---------------------

class MyCheckUrlThread(QThread):
    about_check_url = pyqtSignal(str) #Проверка ответов
    good_requested_url = pyqtSignal(str) #Запись хороших ответов
    bad_requested_url = pyqtSignal(str) #Запись плохих ответов
    status_bar_info = pyqtSignal(int) #Контроль прогресс-бара
    def __init__(self, urls):
        super().__init__()

        self.urls = urls

#-------------Действия в потоке----------------

    def run(self):
        #for start_cycle == number_of_cycless

        i = 1
        for url in self.urls:
            try:
                shit = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
                code = shit.status_code
            except Exception as e:
                # Пусть будет исключение
                code = str(e)
                self.bad_requested_url.emit('{}------{}'.format(url, code))

            self.about_check_url.emit('{}------{}'.format(url, code))

            zaluura = 99 / len(self.urls)

            if i <= 100:
                i += zaluura
                self.status_bar_info.emit(i)

            if code == 200:
                self.good_requested_url.emit('{}------{}'.format(url, code))
            elif code == 307 or 301:
                self.bad_requested_url.emit('{}------{}'.format(url, code))

        #start_cycle += 1

#-------------------Объявление UI-----------------------

class MyWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_RequestCheckerUI()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.urls = self.ui.textEdit
        self.barista = self.ui.CheckPB

        self.result = self.ui.textEdit_2
        self.good = self.ui.textBrowser
        self.bad = self.ui.textBrowser_2

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._on_click_check)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self._erase_fields)

#----------------------Подключения к потоку---------------------------

        self.thread = MyCheckUrlThread(urls=None)
        self.thread.about_check_url.connect(self._on_about_check_url)
        self.thread.good_requested_url.connect(self._good_requested_url)
        self.thread.bad_requested_url.connect(self._bad_requested_url)
        self.thread.status_bar_info.connect(self._statusbarista)
        self.thread.started.connect(self._buttconctrolstop)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self._butocnontrolstart)

#---------Функции интерфейса, выполняемые по сигналу из потока--------

    def _on_click_check(self):
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText('')
        urls = self.urls.toPlainText().strip().split('\n')
        self.barista.setValue(0)
        self.thread.urls = urls
        self.thread.start()


    def _statusbarista(self,int):
        self.barista.setValue(int)


    def _on_about_check_url(self, text):
        self.result.append(text)

    def _good_requested_url(self, text):
        self.good.append(text)

    def _bad_requested_url(self,text):
        self.bad.append(text)

    def _buttconctrolstop(self):
        self.ui.pushButton.setText('Стоп')
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.terminating_thread)
    def _butocnontrolstart(self):
        self.ui.pushButton.setText('Старт')
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.starting_thread)

    def terminating_thread(self):
        self.thread.terminate()

    def starting_thread(self):
        self.thread.start()


    def _erase_fields(self):
        self.ui.textBrowser.setText('')
        self.ui.textBrowser_2.setText('')
        self.ui.textEdit.setText('')
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText('')

#-------------UI запуск------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Предоставьте код потока и PyQt в вопрос (кнопка `править`)

Comment: Не дубликат, но похоже, мне это поможет. Попробую после обеда. Спасибо.

Comment: @gil9red добавил.

Comment: `    import sys
    sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions` похоже на опечатку... Смотрю ваша задачка все ближе к завершению :) Вы хотите разбить список urls на части, чтобы каждую часть отдать определенному потоку?

Comment: @gil9red Ну не совсем потоку. У нас в отделе в основном процессоры 2/2. 2 потока, как я понимаю, уже забиты. Первый - UI, второй - в котором выполняются функции. С прикруткой новых фич, быстродействие стало существенно снижаться. Прочёл, что при подобной работе с сетью, асинхронность даёт существенный прирост к быстродействию. Поэтому я хочу разбить список url, чтобы пока сервер отвечает на один запрос, asyncio переключал контекст, и отсылался второй, потом 3-й. Потом они так же по очереди бы собирали ответы и выводили их. Вообще, выглядит, как будто через callback это было бы лучше, но сложно

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev не помогло. Не понимаю как подстроить это под списки, без файлов. К тому же, тот бьёт по N элементов, а мне нужно на N частей.

Comment: @AgeofCreations во-первых, в примере по ссылке разбивается список, так как `readlines` возвращает именно список строк. Во-вторых, `len(lst)` вернёт вам количество элементов в списке. Простая арифметическая операция деления позволит вам получить количество количество элементов в одной части, чтобы получить N частей.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я, кажется, всё.Абсолютно отупел. До меня наконец-то дошло как это работает. Но я всё ещё не могу понять как мне получить то, что функция вернула. В своё оправдание скажу, что ещё вчера я знал как это делается. А может даже сегодня утром.

Comment: @gil9red всё нормально, я починил. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, путём половины дня поисков и нехитрых тестов, не без участия гениального ума, в итоге придумал себе ответ.

При помощи того же `NumPy` делим нужный список на нужное количество частей (единственным минусом является то, что количество частей постоянно, и изменить его можно только изменив код) таким вот образом:

```
import numpy as np
part0, part1, part2 = np.array_split(urls, 3) 
#urls это список, который включает все введённые UR`L
```

Далее превращаем получившиеся части в строки

```
my_string = '_'.join(part0)  # '_' - разделитель между элементами списка соответственно
my_string2 = '_'.join(part1)
my_string3 = '_'.join(part2)
```

Записываем эти строки в невидимые textEdit (которые я добавил специально для этого)
Можно и в видимые, кстати.

```
self.ui.textEdit_Visual.setText(my_String)
self.ui.textEdit_Visual_2.setText(my_String2)
self.ui.textEdit_Visual_3.setText(my_String3)
```

Оттуда при помощи `urls = self.ui.textEdit_Visual.toPlainText().strip().split('_')`
вытягиваем всё, что надо и работаем с ними. Вуаля. В целом выглядит так:

```
self.ui.textEdit_2.setText('')
urls = self.urls.toPlainText().strip().split('\n')
part0, part1, part2 = np.array_split(urls, 3)
my_String = '_'.join(part0)  # '' - разделитель между элементами списка соответственно
my_String2 = '_'.join(part1)
my_String3 = '_'.join(part2)
self.ui.textEdit_Visual.setText(my_String)
self.ui.textEdit_Visual_2.setText(my_String2)
self.ui.textEdit_Visual_3.setText(my_String3)
working_list = self.urls.toPlainText().strip().split('_')
working_list2 = self.urls.toPlainText().strip().split('_')
working_list3 = self.urls.toPlainText().strip().split('_')
```

Полагаю, это не очень `pythonical` решение, зато сработало. А вот эффективность будем тестить.